# Decode registry values

Tags: python, windows, registry, decode, taskbar

I'm trying to get the value in
`SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband`
from registry to know what is the items in the taskbar

using this code

```
import winreg

access_registry = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None,winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER)

access_key = winreg.OpenKey(access_registry,r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband")
#accessing the key to open the registry directories under
y = winreg.EnumValue(access_key, 0)[1]
yhex = y.hex()
```

but the values that I get is

`` y = b'2\x03\x00\x00L\x00\x00\x00\x01\x14\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00F\x83\x00\x80\x00 \x00\x00\x00e\x03L\x88T\x99\xd8\x01\xc1\xc6Q\x88T\x99\xd8\x01\xa8\xb6\xc6\xda\xdd\xac\xd5\x01\x97\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x01:\x00\x1f\x80\xc8\'4\x1f\x10\\\x10B\xaa\x03.\xe4R\x87\xd6h&\x00\x01\x00&\x00\xef\xbe\x12\x00\x00\x00\x8d\xeb\x86\x84T\x99\xd8\x01\x1a\xa1I\x88T\x99\xd8\x01\xc1\xc6Q\x88T\x99\xd8\x01\x14\x00V\x001\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0TH\xa5\x11\x00TaskBar\x00@\x00\t\x00\x04\x00\xef\xbe\xf0TH\xa5\xf0TH\xa5.\x00\x00\x00tN\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?}\x8c\x00T\x00a\x00s\x00k\x00B\x00a\x00r\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x0e\x012\x00\x97\x01\x00\x00\x87O\x07I \x00FILEEX~1.LNK\x00\x00|\x00\t\x00\x04\x00\xef\xbe\xf0TH\xa5\xf0TH\xa5.\x00\x00\x00uN\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00R\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x9cD\x00F\x00i\x00l\x00e\x00 \x00E\x00x\x00p\x00l\x00o\x00r\x00e\x00r\x00.\x00l\x00n\x00k\x00\x00\x00@\x00s\x00h\x00e\x00l\x00l\x003\x002\x00.\x00d\x00l\x00l\x00,\x00-\x002\x002\x000\x006\x007\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00"\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\xef\xbe\x02\x00U\x00s\x00e\x00r\x00P\x00i\x00n\x00n\x00e\x00d\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00+\x00\xef\xbe\xc1\xc6Q\x88T\x99\xd8\x01\x1c\x00B\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x00\xef\xbe\x02\x00M\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00.\x00W\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00o\x00w\x00s\x00.\x00E\x00x\x00p\x00l\x00o\x00r\x00e\x00r\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x9b\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9a\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00`<\xc4\xae\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00C:\\Users\\{username}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Quick Launch\\User Pinned\\TaskBar\\File Explorer.lnk `` ...

and

`yhex= 320300004c0000000114020000000000c000000000000046830080002000000065034c885499d801c1c651885499d801a8b6c6daddacd501970100000000000001000000000000000000000000000000a0013a001f80c827341f105c1042aa032ee45287d668260001002600efbe120000008deb86845499d8011aa149885499d801c1c651885499d80114005600310000000000f05448a511005461736b42617200400009000400efbef05448a5f05448a52e000000744e01000000010000000000000000000000000000003f7d8c005400610073006b00420061007200000016000e01320097010000874f0749200046494c4545` ...

Is there a way to get the text only from `y` by decoding or another way?

+I tried so many decoders software and online but I couldn't find a way

Comment: so what is your expected output

Comment: @Xxjames07-  I want this text only `\\Users\\{username}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Quick Launch\\User Pinned\\TaskBar\\games.lnk` and there is more like this for other files but this is just an example